# Symfony Easy Admin Bundle: Preload nested form data - Fails Entity of type ...must be managed

Tags: php, symfony, easyadmin, easyadmin3

I'm trying to create a nested form for these three instances, where the inventory has default data, and the nested form `InventoryProduct` has all the Products in the database by default in the form.

- `Inventory` (has one or more `InventarioProduct`) - `Id`, `StartDate`, `EndDate`
- `InventoryProduct` - `Id`, `Product`, `Units`, `RejectedUnits`, `QuarantineUnits`
- `Product` - `Id`, `Name`, `Inci`, some other data from product

So we add to `InventoryCrudCrontroller` the `createEntityMethod`:

```
public function createEntity(string $entityFqcn)
    {
        $inventory= new Inventory();
        $inventory->setStartDate(new DateTime('now'));
        $inventory->setEndDate(null);

        $productRepository= $this->entityManager->getRepository(MateriaPrima::class);

        $products= $productRepository->findAll();

        foreach ($products as $product) {
            $inventoryProduct= new InventoryProduct();
            $inventoryProduct->setProduct($product);
            $inventoryProduct->setUnits(0);
            $inventoryProduct->setUnitsRejected(0);
            $inventoryProduct->setUnitsQuarantine(0);
            $inventoryProduct->setInventory($inventory);

            $inventory->addInventarioProduct($inventoryProduct);
        }
```

And on the `configureFields` method on `InventoryCrudCrontroller`:

```
public function configureFields(string $pageName): iterable
    {

        if (Crud::PAGE_EDIT === $pageName || Crud::PAGE_NEW == $pageName) {
            return [
                DateTimeField::new('startDate')
                    ->setColumns(6)
                    ->setValue(new DateTime()),
                DateTimeField::new('endDate')
                    ->setColumns(6),
                CollectionField::new('products', 'Products:')
                    ->onlyOnForms()
                    ->allowAdd()
                    ->allowDelete()
                    ->setEntryIsComplex(false)
                    ->setEntryType(InventoryProductType::class)
                    ->renderExpanded(true)
                    ->setFormTypeOptions(
                        [
                            'by_reference' => false,
                        ]
                    )
                    ->setColumns(12),
```

And we add the class `InventoryProductType` for the customs form:

```
class InventoryProducts extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {

        $builder
            ->add(
                'product',
                EntityType::class,
                ['class' => Product::class, 'label' => '-']
            )
            ->add('units')
            ->add('unitsRejected')
            ->add('unitsQuarantine')
            ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => InventoryProduct::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

When we try to add another registry, we got:

> Entity of type "App\Entity\Inventory" passed to the choice field must
> be managed. Maybe you forget to persist it in the entity manager?

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error tell you that you are using an entity of type `App\Entity\Inventory` which is not managed by the entity manager.

If you look into your code, you are creating a new entity in your `createEntity` method, but never persisted it.

You could either persist it in your method like:

```
public function createEntity(string $entityFqcn)
    {
        $inventory= new Inventory();
        $inventory->setStartDate(new DateTime('now'));
        $inventory->setEndDate(null);
        $this->entityManager->persist($inventory);

        $productRepository= $this->entityManager->getRepository(MateriaPrima::class);

        $products= $productRepository->findAll();
        
        foreach ($products as $product) {
            $inventoryProduct= new InventoryProduct();
            $inventoryProduct->setProduct($product);
            $inventoryProduct->setUnits(0);
            $inventoryProduct->setUnitsRejected(0);
            $inventoryProduct->setUnitsQuarantine(0);
            $inventoryProduct->setInventory($inventory);
            $this->entityManager->persist($inventoryProduct);

            $inventory->addInventarioProduct($inventoryProduct);
        }
    }
```

[Or add cascading persist on your entity.](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.9/reference/working-with-associations.html#transitive-persistence-cascade-operations)